# Lazy loaded template-driven nested forms

Tags: angular

How do you inject ControlContainer to a lazy loaded component? Whenever I toggle the form, I get the following error:

`NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(ChildFormModule)[NgForm -> NgForm -> NgForm -> NgForm]`

The ControlContainer is being provided in the @Component decorator in the child component:

```
@Component({
    ...
    viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
```

In the parent component.html:

```
<ng-container #LazyChildForm></ng-container>
```

In the parent component.ts:

```
    @ViewChild('LazyChildForm', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) containerRef: ViewContainerRef;
...

await import('@form/widget/child-form/child-form.module').then(({ ChildFormModule }) => {

            this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(ChildFormModule).then((moduleFactory) => {
            const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
            const componentFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildFormComponent);
            this.containerRef.createComponent(componentFactory, null, moduleRef.injector);
        });
```

Here is the ChildFormModule:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ChildFormComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule
    ],
    exports: [ChildFormComponent],
    entryComponents: [
        ChildFormComponent
    ]
})
export class ChildFormModule {
    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
    public resolveComponentFactory(): ComponentFactory<ChildFormComponent> {
        return this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildFormComponent);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get the parent NgForm to be injected? This would normally work with a non-lazy loaded child form.

Comment: Imoort FormsModule inside lazy load module too

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Oh sorry, the module also has FormsModule. Let me add that to the post.